# Angular Backend HTTP Request

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to send an HTTP POST request to my backend in Ruby on Rails,
Unfortunately, the backend does not receive any request.

Heres my code:

```
const params = new HttpParams()
        .set('subject', this.dialogForm.controls['subject'].value)
        .set('start_date', moment(this.dialogForm.controls['startDatePicker'].value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toString())
        .set('due_date', moment(this.dialogForm.controls['dueDatePicker'].value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').toString())
        .set('description', this.dialogForm.controls['description'].value);
      console.log(params);

      this.http.post(API_BASE_URL + 'angular_calendar/custom_meetings/create', ' ', {params})
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError)
        );
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this

Comment: http requests are only sent when the observable returned by `post()` is subscribed to.

Comment: Observables are lazy. You need to subscribe to them to trigger them. `this.http.post(...).subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http requests are only sent when the observable returned by `post()` is subscribed to.

```
this.http.post(API_BASE_URL + 'angular_calendar/custom_meetings/create', ' ', {params}).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
).subscribe(result => {
    // do something with the result
});
```